# How to generate "requirement.txt" file for robot framework project

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have a API test automation project that is written using robot framework and I wanted to generate the requirement.txt file for this project.

I've tried below two options and having below issues.

1. `pipreqs` - This will only include the requirements for python libraries that are added in the project. Libraries for the .robot files are not getting included.
2. `pip freeze > requirements.txt` - This will add all the libraries that are installed on my PC. I just need the required libraries only.

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You should repeat those procedures in a `virtualenv`. You will need to install Robot Framework and the libraries you need for your tests. Do a test run and then the `pip freeze` will show only the modules you installed.

Comment: I initially didn't have a ```virtualenv```. So I created a virtual environment using ```python -m venv .venv``` command. And then when I execute the ```pip freeze > requirement.txt``` command it again pull all the libraries that are on my PC. Seems like the virtual environment is also contain all the libraries in my PC.

Comment: You used the system `pip`. You need to activate the `virtualenv`. I would try to locate the script activate in `.venv/bin` (and then `source .venv/bin/activate`) or in `.venv\\Scripts\\activate`.